# Log only errors in MongoDB logs

Tags: mongodb, logging

Is there any options for only logging the errors in MongoDB log files?

With the current configuration, it seems that every request to Mongo server is logged in log files:

```
Wed Sep 17 08:08:07.030 [conn117] insert my_database.myCol ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:243505 285ms
Wed Sep 17 08:08:54.447 [conn101] command anotherDatabase.$cmd command: { findandmodify: "myCol", query: { ... }, new: 0, remove: 0, upsert: 0, fields: {...}, update: {...} } update: {...} ntoreturn:1 idhack:1 nupdated:1 fastmod:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:124172 reslen:248 124ms
Wed Sep 17 08:10:24.370 [conn95] command my_database.$cmd command: { count: "cms.myCol", query: { ... }, fields: null } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:197368 reslen:48 197ms
...
```

The current configuration is:

```
# mongodb.conf

dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
logappend=true
```

How can be the configuration updated to only log errors?

Running `Mongo shell version: 2.4.10`:

```
$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.10
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Appending [`quiet=true`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--quiet) will reduce a lot of output.

---

Perhaps it is impossible to avoid any output information except error on current stage.
Appending `slowms=threshold` to configuration file can reduce normal log output further.
`threshold` is a integer value (milliseconds). It means if one operation duration doesn't exceed this value, normal log information won't output. The default value is 100.

Also, you can change this value by another way if the instance is running.

```
var slowms = theValueYouWant; 
var level = db.getProfilingStatus().was;
db.setProfilingLevel(level, slowms);
```

Comment: Still getting `... insert test.myCol ninserted:5000` messages. However, `connection accepted` messages are gone

Comment: @Ionică Bizău, That's strange. I didn't get any message on the log while inserting. My version is 2.4.8, 2.6.4.

Comment: The message about insert is logged because it is slow (> 100ms by default). You can change the behavior with [setProfilingLevel](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/).

Comment: I don't want such messages to be logged. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Wizard Tested is and it works! However, is there any way to ignore `info` logs? Example `Thu Sep 25 18:25:40.945 [conn227] info DFM::findAll(): extent 0:3000 was empty, skipping ahead. ns:mono.sessions`