# How to run mongodb instance in ERROR log level mode?

Tags: java, mongodb-3.6

Not able to run mongodb instance in ERROR log level. As defined by mongodb documentation, by default verbosity is 0 which includes information messages. But increasing verbosity to 1-5 will include debug level messages. I need only error messages to be logged in my log file. I am currently using mongodb-3.6.3 version with java driver at client side.

Is there any way to do it? If yes, how to achieve this? I've already tried reducing logs by adding quiet = true in the config file. But still, a lot of unnecessary logs are generated.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your application.properties file and check the console output after running any MongoRepository query.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=ERROR
```

Comment: Thanks for response but I am not using spring framework at client side. Also, I need configuration for mongod server side.

Comment: @KunalRockstar I am speaking about server-side java(specifically spring boot). In the question you have added tag as java.

Comment: @KunalRockstar Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907692/log-only-errors-in-mongodb-logs is what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I have already mentioned in the question that I tried adding quiet = true in the config file. But still a lot of unnecessary logs are generated.