# How to stop mongoDB logs from docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am facing one issue. I have installed `mongodb` through docker and in my docker logs I am getting some logs coming from `mongoDB` continuously. I am explaining some sample logs below.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-09-20T07:08:46.470+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1632121726:470856][11:0x7f81f6abe700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 229, snapshot max: 229 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 1"}}
```

When I am running `docker logs -f containername` then the above logs are coming continuously which is not stopping at all. I am using the below code to install `mongoDB` inside my `Dockerfile`.

```
# MongoDB
RUN wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org
RUN mkdir -p /data/db
```

Here I need to stop this logs which are writing repeatedly. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: try removing the `-f` option which is to follow the logs: `docker logs containername`

Comment: I did but same logs are coming. I need here to sop those logs not complete moving out from docker logs page.

Comment: if you want the logs to be not generated itself then I am not sure you can do that easily, you'll need to change the log level of the app for it to not generate the logs.

Comment: not sure what is the goal you are trying to achieve, if you want to debug the errors then redirect the logs to a file and then debug using file logs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log only errors in MongoDB logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907692/log-only-errors-in-mongodb-logs)

Comment: @HansKilian, Not getting from this link.

Comment: This seems like the expected behaviour. What is the goal here. Do you want to disable logging completely from that container, or do you just want less logging?

Comment: @super, No, I am not expecting such kind of logs will come again and again. at least once it is ok.

Comment: @subhra_user By default, mongod will log pretty much everything it does. The comments are here to give additional information and clarifying things. Saying you don't expect that gives nothing. I asked you a relevant question which you did not answer. Seems counterproductive.

Comment: Here My issue was the logs I have posted is coming repeatedly and here I need to know Is there any solution available to stop printing same kind of logs multiple times.

Comment: That is extremely unspecific. If you want to change how mongod does logging, look at the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/) and go from there.